# Canonical embedding of Hilbert space in $L^2$ space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, probability-distributions, hilbert-spaces, gaussian, rigged-hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. I am interested in isometries $f\colon H\to L^2(X,\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a probability measure on some measure space $X=(X,\mathcal F)$ where $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. My question is whether there exists a canonical choice of $(X,\mu,f)$ that depends only on $H$ and not "arbitrary" choices like choosing an orthonormal basis for $H$.

For an example of what I mean, here is a construction that only works when $H$ is finite dimensional. Let $X=H$, and for $h\in H$ consider the function $f_h\colon X\to\mathbb C$ given by $f_h(x)=\langle h,x\rangle$. Let $\mu$ be the unique Borel measure on $H$ satisfying $$\int_X e^{i f_h(x)}\ d\mu(x) =e^{-\|h\|^2/2}$$
for all $h\in H$, from which it follows that $h\mapsto f_h$ is an isometry. Note that the $\mu$-expectation of the function $\|x\|^2\colon X\to\mathbb C$ equals $\dim H$.

In fact when $\dim H=\infty$, the analogue of this construction yields a measure supported on "elements of $H$ with infinite magnitude", which can be made sense of rigorously as distributions - elements of the space $\Phi^*$ in a [Gelfand triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space#Formal_definition_(Gelfand_triple)) $(\Phi,H,\Phi^*)$.

Thus, a close variant of my question is to ask whether there exists a canonical construction of a Gelfand triple using only the space $H$ as input.

Comment: What structure does a bare Hilbert space even have, that could tell you to prefer one measure space (or one isomorphism) over another?

Comment: Analogous to your Gaussian example, given a separable Hilbert space $H$, one may always embed it into a Banach (or Hilbert) space $W$ and equip $W$ with a Gaussian measure $\mu$, such that the embedding of $H$ into $L^2(W,\mu)$ is an isometry (not surjective).  But there is no canonical way to choose $W$, and in particular no "biggest" or "smallest" such $W$.

Comment: How can there be "a canonical construction of a Gelfand triple using only the space $H$ as input", if the Gelfand triple depends on the choice of a dense subspace $\Phi$ of $H$? Clearly, there are infinitely many such subspaces.

Comment: It sounds like you might want the right adjoint to the $L^2$ functor.

Comment: @OscarCunningham that is a very elegant way of capturing the sort of construction I am going after. See also my question here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348880/canonical-embedding-of-hilbert-space-in-random-l2 where I attempted to formalize what I was looking for in a slightly different category theoretic manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible, at least in the case when $X=H$, as in your "finite-dimensional" example.

Indeed, suppose that $H$ is infinite dimensional. If you want the measure $\mu$ not to depend on the choice of an orthonormal basis, you have to make $\mu$ spherically invariant. But such a probability measure can only be $\delta_0$, the Dirac measure at $0$. (See details below.) And if $\mu=\delta_0$, then $L^2(H,\mu)$ is one dimensional and hence not isometric to the infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$.

**Details:** Suppose that $\mu\ne\delta_0$ is a spherically invariant probability measure on $H$. Let $\nu$ be the conditional distribution of the vector $x/|x|$ given $x\ne0$, assuming that the distribution of $x$ is $\mu$ (here, $|x|$ denotes the norm of $x$). 
Then $\nu$ is a spherically invariant probability measure on the unit sphere in $H$, and such a probability measure does not exist -- see e.g. [Sudakov, page 24](https://books.google.com/books?id=I5ehm9W58LoC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=%22spherically%20invariant%20measure%22%20%22hilbert%22&source=bl&ots=L1LPR5rBW0&sig=ACfU3U2tfXddEdiPkUJkYKmk3tbdxgIkhg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0ssTH8sDmAhVTK80KHY0LBUAQ6AEwBnoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22spherically%20invariant%20measure%22%20%22hilbert%22&f=false). So, indeed, the only spherically invariant probability measure on $H$ is $\delta_0$.