# Canonical embedding of Hilbert space in random $L^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, probability-distributions, hilbert-spaces, gaussian, random-functions

This question is a followup of [Canonical embedding of Hilbert space in $L^2$ space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348676/canonical-embedding-of-hilbert-space-in-l2-space), where it was essentially shown that there is no canonical way to construct, from an abstract Hilbert space $H$, a space $L^2(X,\mu)$ and an isometric embedding $f\colon H\to L^2(X,\mu)$. Of course it is not hard to construct an embedding in *some* $L^2$, but the problem is that one has to make non-canonical choices in constructing the embedding.

In the spirit of the probabilistic method, I have formulated a new question, which concerns the existence of a canonical random isometric embedding in $L^2$. One could allow the space, $\sigma$-algebra, and measure to all be random as well but I will disallow this, for the sake of simplicity in stating the question rigorously.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Let $(X,\mu)$ and $(\Omega,\mathbb P)$ be measurable spaces equipped with probability measures. Let $f\colon H\times \Omega\to L^2(X,\mu)$ be a measurable map such that
$$
\mathbb P\Bigl(\bigl\{\omega\in\Omega\colon f(\cdot,\omega)\textrm{ is an isometry}\bigr\}\Bigr)=1.
$$
As before, it is not hard given $H$ to construct $(X,\mu,\Omega,\mathbb P,f)$ satisfying these conditions. (Indeed, taking $\Omega=\{1\}$ returns to the situation described in the first paragraph of this question.)

**Question.** Given $H$, does there exist a canonical choice of $(X,\mu,\Omega,\mathcal P,f)$ satisfying these conditions?

---

For example, in the case that $H$ is isomorphic to $\ell_2(\mathbb N)$ one could try to find a canonical random isomorphism and compose this with a suitable isometric embedding of $\ell_2(\mathbb N)$ in some $L^2$ space.

---

In response to the comment, here is a version with (some notion of) "canonicity" formalized.

Let $\textrm{HilbIso}$ be the category whose objects are Hilbert spaces and whose morphisms are Hilbert space isomorphisms. Let $\textrm{HilbRandEmb}$ be the category whose objects are tuples $(H,X,\mu,\Omega,\mathcal P,f)$ satisfying the conditions above, and whose morphisms $(H,X,\mu,\Omega,\mathcal P,f)\to (H',X',\mu',\Omega',\mathcal P',f')$ are triples $(a,b,c)$ where $a\colon H\to H'$ is a Hilbert space isomorphism, $b\colon (X,\mu)\to (X',\mu')$ is a measurable map, and $c\colon (\Omega,\mathbb P)\to(\Omega',\mathbb P')$ is a measurable map such that there is the appropriate commuting square between $f,f'$ and the other data.

**Improved version of question.** Does there exist a functor from $\textrm{HilbIso}$ to $\textrm{HilbRandEmb}$ whose composition with the forgetful functor $\textrm{HilbRandEmb}\to \textrm{HilbIso}$ is the identity?

Comment: There's sort of a general principle that infinite-dimensional spaces don't have "canonical" measures, so I suspect this is hopeless.  But one has to give a precise definition of "canonical" in order to obtain negative results.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @NateEldredge, I have appended to my question a (precisely defined) necessary (but perhaps not sufficient) condition for canonicity, in the sense I meant it.